# Does Warren Buffett have a personal portfolio that is public?

Tags: investing

I see a lot of references to "Warren Buffett's" portfolio, but it looks like most of them are actually just Berkshire Hathaway's 13-F, although most don't reference any source.  Does Warren Buffett have a personal portfolio, or is it just Berkshire Hathaway's portfolio that everyone is referring to?

If it is just Berkshire Hathaway's portfolio, why would anyone want to shadow Warren/Berkshire's buys when they can just invest in Berkshire Hathaway?

If it's not Berkshire (they both have "public" portfolios), why would Warren buy differently than Berkshire?  Just different strategies when representing shareholders?

Comment: Have you seen the price for 1 share of Berkshire Hathaway? It isn't that small an amount of money to get a share.

Comment: @JBKing, BRK.B, which is a basically a "split" of BRK.A (to solve the problem you're referring to), is currently 115 per share.

Comment: The price of the stock is a public perception of the value of the company which may or may not be the same as the total value of its holdings is something else to note.

Comment: (1) Is his portfolio public? You've got the same tools for researching that as I do... (2) Why would he buy (or hold) differently than Berkshire? One obvious answer would be because there are risks/opportunities that are either too small, or too much a personal call, or that aren't publicly traded, or... Many possible reasons for him to diverge in details even if he's following similar principals overall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While Warren Buffet does hold nearly 100% of his wealth in BRK, he does have a personal retirement account of a few million USD at last disclosure.

Individual accounts are not for public consumption; however, he has revealed that he invests in a similar manner as he did as managing partner of Buffett Partnership, Ltd. and its predecessors, in far smaller companies than the current BRK holdings.

Comment: Great answer.  So to "follow" Warren, you just need to invest in BRK, but seeing his latest acquisitions (via 13-F) gives insight into what he currently sees as the most valuable addition to BRK, but this would not necessarily mean it's his favorite investment because he may be picking it partially for diversification (e.g., not to over-invest in Wells Fargo). It seems like investing in BRK is much easier so you do not have to consider re-basing your portfolio each quarter when the 13-F comes out, and also get to "buy in" earlier when BRK does.

Answer (score 0):

It is the Berkshire Hathaway portfolio, most likely, but you'd better ask those people that reference to it that you're referring to.